# A server offer concurrent TCP services to multiple clients

Tags: tcp

Can anyone tell me how a server offer concurrent TCP services to multiple clients

while using only a single thread?

Thanks very much !!

Answer (score 0):

It uses a physical thread provided by the system, but it is able to create as many virtual treads as the system allows/supports(usually one thread per request), assuming a single threaded system, which is pretty uncommon on today servers configurations, and a X86 arch, each thread would get a bit of processor time on each clock run enabling the server to work with multiple requests at "virtually" the same time.

Regards.